# How to get button & its values on on_press in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am working on the Library Management Project. I wanted to create multiple buttons with images which on_press would open the file stored on the specified directory. But the problem is I couldn't able to get or change the properties of the button in the callback function. Which is why I couldn't able to determine which button is pressed and which directory to use?

Note: The directory is stored in db file with the file name as key (which is why I need to get btn text in callback function)

Here's the code which I am facing problem with:

```
# code above this line
       btn1 = Button(text=text,
                      font_size=20,
                      size_hint=(.5, .5),
                      background_normal='images/Black_Clover,_volume_1.jpg',
                      background_down='images/Black_Clover,_volume_1.jpg',
                      on_press=self.callback
                      )
   def callback(self, event):
        print("button pressed")
# code below this line
```

I tried going through many docs but still couldn't find solution. Hope you will help me through this.

Here's full code if you want to debug:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class ReaderApp(App):
    def build(self):
        mainscreen = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')

        # Side Navbar
        navbar = BoxLayout(
            orientation='vertical',
        )
        lib_btn = Button(
            text="Library",
            size_hint=(1, .2)
        )
        settings_btn = Button(
            text="Settings",
            size_hint=(1, .2)
        )
        about_btn = Button(
            text="About",
            size_hint=(1, .2)
        )
        navbar.add_widget(lib_btn)
        navbar.add_widget(settings_btn)
        navbar.add_widget(about_btn)

        # Main Layout
        library = StackLayout(orientation ='lr-tb')
        text = "Black Clover"
        btn1 = Button(text=text,
                      font_size=20,
                      size_hint=(.5, .5),
                      background_normal='images/Black_Clover,_volume_1.jpg',
                      background_down='images/Black_Clover,_volume_1.jpg',
                      on_press=self.callback
                      )
        btn2 = Button(text="Kaguya Sama",
                      font_size=20,
                      size_hint=(.5, .5),
                      background_normal='images/Kaguya-sama_Love_is_War_art.jpg',
                      background_down='images/Kaguya-sama_Love_is_War_art.jpg',
                      on_press=self.callback
                      )
        btn3 = Button(text="Wandering Witch",
                      font_size=20,
                      size_hint=(.5, .5),
                      background_normal='images/Majonotabitabi.jpeg',
                      background_down='images/Majonotabitabi.jpeg',
                      on_press=self.callback
                      )
        btn4 = Button(text="B4",
                      font_size=20,
                      size_hint=(.5, .5),
                      on_press=self.callback
                      )
        library.add_widget(btn1)
        library.add_widget(btn2)
        library.add_widget(btn3)
        library.add_widget(btn4)

        mainscreen.add_widget(navbar)
        mainscreen.add_widget(library)

        return mainscreen

    def callback(self, event):
        print("button pressed")
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ReaderApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the text as an argument to the callback function through a lambda expression:

```
btn4 = Button(text="B4",
                      font_size=20,
                      size_hint=(.5, .5),
                      on_press=lambda: self.callback(text="B4")
                      )
```

And add here the text parameter:

```
def callback(self, event, text):
        print(f"button with {text} pressed")
```

In this way you will be able to identify which button with pressed through it's text